# The CreateFileMapping is failed with security attributes: The revision level is unknown

Tags: visual-c++

I am creating shared file using CreateFileMapping with security attributes on c++. it throws error "**The revision level is unknown**" with elevated & no elevated mode.

CreateFileMapping : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537(v=vs.85).aspx

am i missing something or am i doing wrong?

could you please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <aclapi.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "advapi32.lib")

void main()
{

DWORD dwRes;
PSID pEveryoneSID = NULL, pAdminSID = NULL;
PACL pACL = NULL;
PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD = NULL;
EXPLICIT_ACCESS ea[2];
SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY SIDAuthWorld =
    SECURITY_WORLD_SID_AUTHORITY;
SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY SIDAuthNT = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;

// Create a well-known SID for the Everyone group.
if (!AllocateAndInitializeSid(&SIDAuthWorld, 1,
    SECURITY_WORLD_RID,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    &pEveryoneSID))
{
    _tprintf(_T("AllocateAndInitializeSid Error %u\n"), GetLastError());
    goto Cleanup;
}

// Initialize an EXPLICIT_ACCESS structure for an ACE.
// The ACE will allow Everyone read access to the key.
ZeroMemory(&ea, 2 * sizeof(EXPLICIT_ACCESS));
ea[0].grfAccessPermissions = KEY_READ;
ea[0].grfAccessMode = SET_ACCESS;
ea[0].grfInheritance = NO_INHERITANCE;
ea[0].Trustee.TrusteeForm = TRUSTEE_IS_SID;
ea[0].Trustee.TrusteeType = TRUSTEE_IS_WELL_KNOWN_GROUP;
ea[0].Trustee.ptstrName = (LPTSTR)pEveryoneSID;

// Create a SID for the BUILTIN\Administrators group.
if (!AllocateAndInitializeSid(&SIDAuthNT, 2,
    SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID,
    DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    &pAdminSID))
{
    _tprintf(_T("AllocateAndInitializeSid Error %u\n"), GetLastError());
    goto Cleanup;
}

// Initialize an EXPLICIT_ACCESS structure for an ACE.
// The ACE will allow the Administrators group full access to
// the key.
ea[1].grfAccessPermissions = KEY_ALL_ACCESS;
ea[1].grfAccessMode = SET_ACCESS;
ea[1].grfInheritance = NO_INHERITANCE;
ea[1].Trustee.TrusteeForm = TRUSTEE_IS_SID;
ea[1].Trustee.TrusteeType = TRUSTEE_IS_GROUP;
ea[1].Trustee.ptstrName = (LPTSTR)pAdminSID;

// Create a new ACL that contains the new ACEs.
dwRes = SetEntriesInAcl(2, ea, NULL, &pACL);
if (ERROR_SUCCESS != dwRes)
{
    _tprintf(_T("SetEntriesInAcl Error %u\n"), GetLastError());
    goto Cleanup;
}

// Initialize a security descriptor.  
pSD = (PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR)LocalAlloc(LPTR,
    SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_MIN_LENGTH);
if (NULL == pSD)
{
    _tprintf(_T("LocalAlloc Error %u\n"), GetLastError());
    goto Cleanup;
}

if (!InitializeSecurityDescriptor(pSD,
    SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION))
{
    _tprintf(_T("InitializeSecurityDescriptor Error %u\n"),
        GetLastError());
    goto Cleanup;
}

// Add the ACL to the security descriptor. 
if (!SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(pSD,
    TRUE,     // bDaclPresent flag   
    pACL,
    FALSE))   // not a default DACL 
{
    _tprintf(_T("SetSecurityDescriptorDacl Error %u\n"),
        GetLastError());
    goto Cleanup;
}

// Initialize a security attributes structure.
sa.nLength = sizeof (SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = pSD;
sa.bInheritHandle = FALSE;

// Use the security attributes to set the security descriptor 
HANDLE m_hFileMap = CreateFileMapping(
    INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,               // use paging file
    &sa,                                // default security
    PAGE_READWRITE,                     // read/write access
    0,                                  // maximum object size (high-order DWORD)
    1024,                               // maximum object size (low-order DWORD)
    L"Global\\MyObject");               // name of mapping object

_tprintf(_T("CreateFileMapping result %u\n"), GetLastError());

Cleanup:

if (pEveryoneSID)
    FreeSid(pEveryoneSID);
if (pAdminSID)
    FreeSid(pAdminSID);
if (pACL)
    LocalFree(pACL);
if (pSD)
    LocalFree(pSD);

return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changes for a file mapping object

```
ea[0].grfAccessPermissions = FILE_GENERIC_READ;//KEY_READ

ea[1].grfAccessPermissions = FILE_ALL_ACCESS; //KEY_ALL_ACCESS
```

Comment: did this resolve the issue? I have a similar issue where I updated the dacl while creating global named shared memory from service but the user process with non-admin privilege was not able to access the SM.